# How to install Beagle?

Tags: 11.04, installation

I've been trying to install Beagle on my 11.04 installation of Ubuntu.

The Beagle site says that Beagle is shipped with Ubuntu.  But from the software center in Ubuntu, a search for Beagle returns zero results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The last beagle version was in 10.4 and is no longer in [active development](http://beagle-project.org/Main_Page). You could try the [Lucid Lynx (10.04) package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/beagle). I have seen [tracker](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/tracker) and [cardapio](https://launchpad.net/cardapio) suggested as an alternative.

From the descriptions I think Dash in 11.04 is aiming to be sort of the same thing and more. It is not yet as good as Beagle I admit.